# Would like to change an existing outlet to half-hot

Tags: receptacle

I have an outlet that is fully hot. I would like to make it half-hot instead. There are only TWO wires total going to the outlet; one white and one red. Is it possible to make this outlet half hot with only two wires?

Comment: What do you want with the other half?  Always cold (off)?  Switched by a nearby switch?

Comment: I really don't understand the question.  We need details - What country, a clearer explanation of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

with only 2 wires you wont be able to control the 2nd half. If you just want to cut the power to the 2nd half turn the power off pull the outlet and break the tab between the 2 outlets on the red side. if you want to switch the other 1/2 you will need to pull a wire from the red to a switch and then back to the half you want to switch. You should also run a ground from the outlet to the switch.